# Unable to install new operating systen on chromebook

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bios, chromebook

I forgot what happened to my chromebook, it's an old one that's got a lotta sentimental value to it and it does not boot anything. If I plug in my USB with any OS on it it will just boot into what I think is it's bios? I've tried booting from a file, which is /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi with no luck, I can't reformat the drive since it's built into the motherboard and I think the chromebook doesn't have a bios built in anyway. [BIOS screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqs71.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you select boot manager? And/or what happens when you do continue? How did you put the Ubuntu image onto the flash drive?

Comment: When I select boot manager I get a list of options: Boot Options, Driver Options, Console Options, Boot from File, Set Boot next Value, Set Time out Value, and Reset System. I've tried adding my boot disk in Boot Options which hasn't worked, and I've tried Reset System and Boot from File. When I boot from file I get some grub menu that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Oh take a photo of the grub menu - that is probably how you get to Ubuntu

Comment: Okay, so magically when I went to get to the menu again it worked? before it'd say something about grub and send me to some command line but now it just boots off the flash drive like normal. Thanks!